# Json data is not showing when subgrid is expanded

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that when a row is clicked, it needs to expand and show secondary results. I have the row expanding but the subgrid isn't being populated.

Javascript for jqGrid

```
var mainGridPrefix = "s_";
$("#contractSearchResults").jqGrid({
    loadingtext: '<img src="~/Content/Images/loading.gif"/>',
    url: '/Search/GetContractResultsJson?searchTerm=' + $('#searchTerm').attr("value"),
    //pager: '#pager',
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames: ['Contract #', 'Versions', 'Version Name', 'Supplier', 'Description', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Portfolio Specialist'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'Contract #', resizable: true, sortable: false },
        { name: 'Versions', resizable: true, sortable: false },
        { name: 'VersionName', resizable: true, sortable: false },
        { name: 'Supplier', resizable: true, sortable: false },
        { name: 'tDescription', resizable: true, sortable: false },
        { name: 'StartDate', resizable: true, sortable: false },
        { name: 'EndDsate', resizable: true, sortable: false },
        { name: 'PortfolioSpecialist', resizable: true, sortable: false }
    ],
    rowNum: 25,
    rowList: [25, 50, 75, 100],
    height: '100%',
    width: '900',
    shrinkToFit: '900',
    gridview: true,
    idPrefix: mainGridPrefix,    
    jsonReader: {
        rows: "rowData",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        cell: 'cell',
        id: 'id'
    },
    loadComplete: function () {
        loadComplete();
    },
    subGrid: true,
    beforeProcessing: function (data) {
        var rows = data.rows, l = rows.length, i, item, subgrids = {};
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            item = rows[i];
            if (item.actionSet) {
                subgrids[item.id] = item.actionSet;
                alert(subgrids[item.id]);
            }
        }
        data.userdata = subgrids;
    },
    subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
        var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>"),
        pureRowId = $.jgrid.stripPref(mainGridPrefix, rowId),
        subgrids = $("#contractSearchResults").getGridParam("userData");
        $subgrid.appendTo('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId));
        $subgrid.jqGrid({
            datatype: 'local',
            data: subgrids[pureRowId],
            colNames: ['ContractID', 'Price Protection Date', 'Approval Status'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'ContractID', key: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'Price Protection Date', formatter: 'date', sorttype: 'date' },
                { name: 'Approval Status' }
            ],
            index: 'ContractID',
            height: '100%',
            rowNum: 10000,
            autoencode: true,
            autowidth: true,
            localReader: {
                repeatitems: true
            },
            gridview: true,
            idPrefix: rowId + "_",
            viewrecords: true
        });
    }
});
```

And this is how I'm forming the Json

```
public JsonResult MockJsonForContract()
{
    var rowData = GetMockContracts().Select(x => new
    {
        id = x.ContractNumber,
        cell = new[] 
        { 
            x.ContractNumber, 
            x.VersionCount.ToString(),
            x.VersionName,
            x.ManufacturerName,
            x.ContractDescription,
            x.VersionStartDate.ToShortDateString(),
            x.VersionEndDate.ToShortDateString(),
            x.PortfolioSpecialist,                                
        },
        subGrid = new[]
        {
            x.ContractID.ToString(),
            x.PriceProtectionEndDate.ToShortDateString(),
            x.ApprovalStatus
        }
    }).ToList();

    //Instantiate the JsonResult object
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

    //Set the behavior to allow gets
    result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

    //Add the JSON array to the JsonResult object
    result.Data = new
    {
        total = 1,
        page = 1,
        records = rowData.Count(),
        rows = rowData
    };

    //Return the Json Object
    return result;
}


public IEnumerable<ContractSearchResultsModel> GetMockContracts()
{
    yield return new ContractSearchResultsModel
    {
        ContractID = 1,
        ContractNumber = "M00001",
        VersionCount = 1,
        VersionName = "Mock Contract",
        ManufacturerName = "Mock Name",
        ContractDescription = "This is a mock contract",
        VersionStartDate = DateTime.Now,
        VersionEndDate = new DateTime(2015, 12, 12),
        PortfolioSpecialist = "Mock Name",
        PriceProtectionEndDate = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1),
        ApprovalStatus = "Approved"
    };
    yield return new ContractSearchResultsModel
    {
        ContractID = 2,
        ContractNumber = "M00002",
        VersionCount = 1,
        VersionName = "Mock Contract",
        ManufacturerName = "Mock Name",
        ContractDescription = "This is a mock contract",
        VersionStartDate = DateTime.Now,
        VersionEndDate = new DateTime(2015, 12, 12),
        PortfolioSpecialist = "Mock Name",
        PriceProtectionEndDate = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1),
        ApprovalStatus = "Approved"
    };
    yield return new ContractSearchResultsModel
    {
        ContractID = 3,
        ContractNumber = "M00003",
        VersionCount = 1,
        VersionName = "Mock Contract",
        ManufacturerName = "Mock Name",
        ContractDescription = "This is a mock contract",
        VersionStartDate = DateTime.Now,
        VersionEndDate = new DateTime(2015, 12, 12),
        PortfolioSpecialist = "Mock Name",
        PriceProtectionEndDate = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1),
        ApprovalStatus = "Approved"
    };
    yield return new ContractSearchResultsModel
    {
        ContractID = 4,
        ContractNumber = "M00004",
        VersionCount = 1,
        VersionName = "Mock Contract",
        ManufacturerName = "Mock Name",
        ContractDescription = "This is a mock contract",
        VersionStartDate = DateTime.Now,
        VersionEndDate = new DateTime(2015, 12, 12),
        PortfolioSpecialist = "Mock Name",
        PriceProtectionEndDate = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1),
        ApprovalStatus = "Approved"
    };
}
```

The main problem is when I'm not using the mock data, I am calling a service to get the data and I want to only call the service once since queries could return 100k or more rows.

Is it an issue with how the Json is being formed or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
beforeProcessing: function (data) {
    var rows = data.rows, l = rows.length, i, item, subgrids = {};
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        item = rows[i];
        if (item.actionSet) {
            subgrids[item.id] = item.actionSet;
            alert(subgrids[item.id]);
        }
    }
    data.userdata = subgrids;
}
```

The issue was item.actionSet needed to be changed to reference the right part of the JSON data I was sending back to the grid.

This is what it needed to be

```
var rows = data.rows, l = rows.length, i, item, subgrids = {};
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        item = rows[i];
        if (item.subGrid) {
            subgrids[item.id] = item.subGrid;
        }
    }
    data.userdata = subgrids;
```